# Stroking lines and computing line joins

Tags: java, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry

does anyone have any tips/ideas on how to calculate Round line joins?
The device I'm working on only supports single width lines. 
I am trying to implement basic stroking with only round line joins.

Some things I'm messing with are below. 
It's not much, but I hope to get some ideas on how to handle the different cases when two lines join, based on any replies.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have had some progress with the outer join:

a. Get clockwise order vertices (I get these from flattened glyphs)
b. Grab 3 vertices
c. Compute normal of line A (prevX, prevY) -> (currentX, currentY)
d. Compute normal of line B (currentX, currentY) -> (nextX, nextY)

I compute normals using a left turn on the current clockwise vertices
normal = (deltaY, -deltaX) // Thanks Andreas

```
Vec2[] computeNormals(float prevX, float prevY, float x, float y, float nextX, float nextY) {
    float dx1 = x - prevX;
    float dy1 = y - prevY;

    float dx2 = x - nextX;
    float dy2 = y - nextY;

    Vec2 normal1 = new Vec2(dy1, -dx1).normalize();
    Vec2 normal2 = new Vec2(dy2, -dx2).normalize();
    if (normal1.angleDeg() > normal2.angleDeg()) {
        normal2.rot((float) Math.PI);
    }

    return (new Vec2[] { normal1, normal2 });
}
```

e. Determine outer join arc angle from atan2(deltaY, -deltaX)

```
void computeArc(VertexBuffer dest, float x, float y, float arcRadius, Vec2 normal1, Vec2 normal2) {
    // Angle from Vecto2D is atan2(y, x)
    float angleStart = normal1.angle();
    float angleEnd = normal2.angle();

    float angleInc = (float) Math.PI / 4f; // Temporary, need to find a way to determine numVertices for a Pen of a given width
    while (angleStart > angleEnd) {
        angleStart -= (float) (2f * Math.PI);
    }
    for (float a = angleStart; a <= angleEnd; a += angleInc) {
        float vx = x + ((float) Math.cos(a) * arcRadius);
        float vy = y + ((float) Math.sin(a) * arcRadius);
        dest.addVertex(vx, vy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your device can draw filled circles, you could put a filled circle at the 2 end points, and one at every line joint.